# как сравнить пароль зашифрованный c помощью md5 с обычным

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, password

Я совсем новичек в php, хотел сделать простую страницу регистрация\авторизация. Регистрацию сделал без проблем, а вот с авторизацией вопрос.
При регистрации я хеширую, или как там правильно, через md5(), как его сравнить с введенным при авторизации паролем?!? Сначала попробовал просто их сравнить, потом понял что это уж очень глупо, тоже хешировал введеный пароль и сравнил, но тоже чего-то не работает(

Comment: Для начала надо научиться задавать вопросы. Сейчас твой вопрос звучит так: "Расскажите, как есть борщ? Я сначала пробовал вилкой, но потом понял что это глупо. После этого попробовал есть ложкой, то все равно не получается". МЫ, как бы, не знаем, что ты пробовал и что у тебя не получается. Сравнивать хэши - это наиболее логичный вариант. Но как можно накосячить при сравнении - мы даже не догадываемся. поэтому надо показывать, что ты делал, а не рассказывать.

Comment: зашифрованный с бд и зашифрованный при вводе сравнивать, должно работать...

Comment: md5 - **не** шифрование. И вообще использовать его для "защиты" паролей - **нельзя**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правильно написали в комментариях, md5 - не шифрование, а хэширование. И использовать MD5 для "защиты" паролей нельзя. Использовать надо специально предназначенные для этого функции, password_hash() и [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php).

Это означает, в частности, что в запросе проверить валидность пароля нельзя, надо сначала достать его из БД, а потом проверить соответствующий функцией. Пример того, как это правильно сделать при использовании подготовленных выражений в PDO, можно посмотреть [здесь](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash)

Comment: даже соль не поможет? типа md5($email.$pass.$salt)

Comment: @DaemonHK нет. У хэширования есть три уязвимости - подбор по словарю, радужные таблицы и брутфорс. Соль помогает только от таблиц. А от брутфорса как раз помогает правильный алгоритм.

Comment: Так а что даст брутфорс? Правильный хэш? И что дальше с ним делать, если нет доступа к БД?

Comment: `md5 - не шифрование, а хэширование. И использовать его для "защиты" паролей нельзя. ... Использовать надо ... password_hash()`. С виду кажется что вы говорите что хэширование - плохо и использовать нельзя и приводите алгоритм хэширования. @DaemonHK На самом деле **главное** различие `md5` и `password_hash` в скорости брутфорса, для md5 он составляет миллионы (а то и миллиарды) в секунду, у аналога намного медленнее (тем более с солью). зная хэш+соль+алгоритм хэширования(md5) хацкер за день подберет и узнает пароль пользователя, используя `password_hash`+соль задача усложнится в разы

Comment: @Manitikyl а как же длина и сложность пароля? Или для md5 даже это не актуально? Просто сейчас этих алгоритмов хэширования, мама не горюй. На 2 работах юзали/юзают md5 (на одной с солью, на второй просто md5 0_о), вот и думаешь, на что конкретно переходить.

Comment: @DaemonHK а причем тут длина и сложность пароля если в секунду можно перебрать миллионы. Представьте сколько это в час, день. Проблема `md5` тут в математической простоте генерации хэша, для современных видеокарт (а md5 обычно брутфорсят на них) такие вычисления - семечки. В гугле куча статей где шарящие люди (подготовленные) подбирают пароли состоящие из 12-14 символов (включая спец.символы) за несколько секунд. Вот вам и `md5` ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Manitikyl ок, спасибо большое! Так альтернатива какая? password_hash() только?

Comment: @DaemonHK ну я думаю на гитхабе есть пару либ от мастеров, но `password_hash()` вполне нормальная и адекватная функция, ибо создавалась как раз для надежного и безопасного хранения хэшей паролей. Использовать её вполне оправданно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93882/discussion-between-daemonhk-and-manitikyl).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вычислить хеш от введенного пароля и сравнить хеши введенного пароля с сохраненным.

Скажем, так

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  users
WHERE
  name = :name AND
  password_hash = MD5(:password);
```

Comment: :name и :password  нужно заменить на мой логин и пароль? Объясни поподробнее)

Comment: @ВладРогов это так называемые Подготавливаемые запросы https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: не надо торопиться с ответом, если вы не владеете вопросом. Ответ должен быть **качественным, и полезным для всех читателей**, а не решать только одну опечатку  одного только беспомощного автора.